# Limitations of APEX for WebApp

Tags: .net, oracle, web-applications, oracle-apex

I have a currently joined a project and the customer the team supports gave a layout of requirements. To my idea these requirements are very demanding to be on a Web Application level. It needs to handle daily transactions, list update alerts, etc. I pursue the idea of using .NET webapplication. The ideas have come up to use APEX. I am not familar at all with. Reading up on it I found that it is basically a Oracle front end application that runs off a Oracle DB. The front end is limited to html/css modification and only report generating? So I really dont know the real limitations I would have as a developer by using APEX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked on [apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html)?  Lots of resources there for getting to know the capabilities of Apex.

Apex is a tool for creating web-based applications that run on top of an Oracle database. Since it works using HTML and Javascript it can do pretty much whatever can be done with any other web-based application platform - more or less easily than others depending on what it is you want to do.

Your question is quite vague about the "demanding requirements".  Perhaps pick one you think would be a problem for Apex and describe it in more detail?

Comment: Two requirements that I am not sure to work for APEX: let say workflows or data updates in a listview

Comment: I guess I am not really trying to know the capabilities, but really the limitations

Comment: Workflows - Apex doesn't have built-in workflow functionality, but it could certainly integrate with a workflow engine (I have done that).

Comment: "Updates in a listview" - I have no idea what they are!?

Comment: Workflow engine, so from what you're saying I would have to bring in a third party tool and "Updates in a listview" meaning if I had a report/list of data from the DB on a page where a user could edit the data dynamically to the DB.

Comment: Workflow - yes.  Updates in a listview - sounds like what Apex calls a tabular form - i.e. an updatable report.  This has limitations: 1 per page and max. 50 data values per row.

Comment: So to those questions. Me being a developer, where would my skills come in here. The workflow of the third party tool?could you refer me to one that you used? and for the tabular reports? wouldn't this or all the custom code have to be done in pl/sql? Also from using the tabular form you speak of would I be able to integrate that with the workflow engine to generate a notification to users when that report is updated?

Comment: We used Oracle Workflow: http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/workflow.101/b10285.pdf which is I believe obsolete now (replaced by BPEL?)  Since Oracle Workflow was based on Oracle tables and packages we were able to build our own UI for it using Apex.  On my current project with a different company we simply built our own simple workflow system.

Comment: Tabular forms: for more complex requirements you can write PL/SQL, but Apex includes functionality to build a tabular form declaratively - i.e. specify the table/view you want to base it on, specify the columns you want to display and what kind of control to use for each (text, select, checkbox etc.)

Comment: Is it possible to handle access controls for users at the column level? Ad-hoc report creation? or dynamic charting?

Comment: As an Apex developer you WILL have to expect to get to know PL/SQL to some extent, unless all your needs are served by basic out-of-the-box Apex "form on a table" and "report on a table" type pages.

Comment: You said for more complex requirements you can write PL/SQL. well I am a C# developer, so not too familar with PL/SQL, but that it is a query language, so it will not be able to do things I would need something like C# to do. Is that correct?

Comment: Access controls - yes.  Ad hoc report creation - not really, unless you set your users up as developers!  Charting - yes; dynamic charting - probably not if that means your users deciding what to chart at run time...

Comment: Like what C# are you asking of what C# should be able to do that PL/SQL can't. well I dont know PL/SQL, but I know SQL and I know C# and SQL is not made to act as general purpose language like C#? so does PL/SQL change this

Comment: PL/SQL is a procedural language that integrates well with Oracle SQL.  So you can write procedures and functions in it and call them.  It is nowhere near as general-purpose as C#, it is specifically intended for writing code to manipulate Oracle data.  I'm afraid that if this project goes ahead with Apex this is going to be a big paradigm shift for you; you probably won't like it any more than I would like to have to start using C#!

Comment: One last question, is it able to handle a usage summary for pages on the front end? and can users subscribes to reports to be notified with the data changes?

Comment: that would be built with PL/SQL?

Comment: But not necessarily - it could just be a SQL report in an Apex page.  Depends on the exact requirements really.

Answer (score 5):

I'm an advocate of Apex and know little about .Net: but the choice of development platform and architecture must include consideration not only of the requirements and capabilities (although these are very important, of course) but also the skills and experience of most of the developers and maintainers of the system.

There's not much you *can't* do in both Apex and .Net - but if the team is not skilled in Apex but is experienced in .Net that would be a major factor in choosing .Net instead.

Other considerations are cost and simplicity - Apex, I suspect, is a lot simpler than .Net (less moving parts, tighter integration with the database) and cheaper (i.e. free with the Oracle licence).

(plus: what Tony said.)